# C# | How to replace input string with TValue in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Can someone tell me how i can replace each letter from string with TValue from Dictionary?
I am trying to make converter from ANSI TO MORSE CODE AND REVERSE.

```
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
      
        var morsecode = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
            { 'A', "._" },
            { 'B', "_..." },
            { 'C', "_._." },
            { 'D', "_.." },
            {'E',"." },
            {'F',".._." },
            {'G',"__." },
            {'H',"...." },
            {'I',".." },
            {'J',".___" },
            {'K',"_._" },
            {'L',"._.." },
            {'M',"__" },
            {'N',"_." },
            {'O',"___" },
            {'P',".__." },
            {'R',"._." },
            {'S',"..." },
            {'T',"_" },
            {'U',".._" },
            {'W',".__" },
            {'X',"_.._" },
            {'Y',"_.__" },
            {'Z',"__.." } };
            
            foreach(var x in morsecode.Keys)
        {
            if (x.Equals(input))
            {
                input.Replace(x,morsecode.Values.ToString());
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming input contains only characters from morsecode dictionary, you can just replace each character in input with sequence of characters (string) from dictionary, and create new string:

```
var output = new String(input.SelectMany(ch => morsecode[ch]).ToArray());
```

Or replace input characters with strings and concat them - result is same:

```
var output = String.Concat(input.Select(ch => morsecode[ch]));
```

Note: How are you going to distinguish separate letters and words in output? Probably it makes sense not to combine everything in the output string, or use some delimiter. E.g. this way you will get an array of words which are arrays of separate Morse codes:

```
input.Split() // get words
     .Select(word => word.Select(ch => morsecode[ch]).ToArray())
     .ToArray()
```

Comment: Just want to make encoder and decoder on Switch. i am practicing.
Thanks for your answer. It will help me 100%.